# Problem with SSL and Proxy 1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: proxy, composer-php, environment-variables, installation

I want to install Composer by this command "php composer-setup.php". But I got this message:

> The "http://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Operation timed out
>   Retrying...

I am behind a proxy, so wanted to solve this problem by setting this: set http_proxy=https://~

Now I got this message:

> The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
>   Failed to enable crypto
>   failed to open stream: operation failed
>   Retrying...

Can somebody help...?